# elasticsearch wildcard string search query with '>'

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I have string field that mapped as 'not_analyzed'.
Each string has '>' simbol and need to find some string with it.

> string e.g)
>
> one>two>tree>four>...

with below query, I could get result I expected.

> "query": {
>       "wildcard": {
>          "activityseq": {
>             "value": "one*"
>          }
>       } }

but when added '>' in value, It's not.

> "query": {
>       "wildcard": {
>          "activityseq": {
>             "value": "one>*"
>          }
>       } }

or

> "query": {
>       "wildcard": {
>          "activityseq": {
>             "value": "one>*"
>          }
>       } }

Any Idea of this?

---

document sample

> { "_index": "pm", "_type": "dmcase_00090", "_id":
>   "AVQ7Wjht0bpb6L5Mykw7", "_version": 1, "_score": 1, "_source": {
>   "endat": "1970-01-12T06:08:00+09:00", "startat":
>   "1970-01-06T23:02:00+09:00", "activityseq":
>   "MakeTicket>FirstContact>ArrangeSurvey>MakeTicket>InformClientSurvey>ArrangeSurvey>Survey>Survey>InternRepair>RepairReady>InternRepair>SendTicketToFinAdmin>TicketReady>ReadyInformClient",
>   "events": [ { ... some events

---

query + result

1.

> "query": {
>           "wildcard": {
>              "activityseq": {
>                 "value": "maketicket*"
>              }
>           }
>       }
>
> result : data as I expect

2.

> "query": {
>           "wildcard": {
>              "activityseq": {
>                 "value": "maketicket>*"
>              }
>           }
>       }

result

> "hits": {
>         "total": 0,
>         "max_score": null,
>         "hits": []    }

3.

> "query": {
>           "wildcard": {
>              "activityseq.raw": {
>                 "value": "maketicket*"
>              }
>           }
>       }

result

> "hits": {
>         "total": 0,
>         "max_score": null,
>         "hits": []    }

4.

> "query": {
>           "wildcard": {
>              "activityseq": {
>                 "value": "maketicket>*"
>              }
>           }
>       }

result

> "caused_by": {
>                     "type": "json_parse_exception",
>                     "reason": "Unrecognized character escape '>' (code 62)\n at [Source: [B@61201912; line: 5, column: 37]"
>                  }

Comment: I've tried on my end and all of the above queries do return the document as expected. Can you update your question with the output your get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` (rename `your_index` to match your actual index name) ?

Comment: "myTable": {
"properties": {
"seqstring": {
"type": "string",
"fields": {
"raw": {
"type": "string",
"index": "not_analyzed"
}
}
},
It's part of my metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs to look like this and it will work, i.e. you need to match on the `seqstring.raw` sub-field, since that's the one which is `not_analyzed`

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "seqstring.raw": {
        "value": "one>*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I added '.raw', it returned nothing. this mean index is not set as not_analyzed?

Comment: What is the difference between `activityseq` (in your question) and `seqstring` (in your comment)?

Comment: same field, just renamed it on here

Comment: That's weird then... it works on my end with the same mapping and `one>two>...` value, not sure what's wrong then.

Comment: I added one of mu documents. events field is mapped as nested but I'm sure that activityseq is only one in each document.

Comment: Ok, then can you also show exactly the query you're making? i.e. with the exact value, not dummy ones

Comment: Ok, since the raw field is not analyzed, you need to use the exact same case, i.e. `MakeTicket*` in query 3 and for query 4, please use the `activityseq.raw` field

Comment: Use the same casing, i.e. uppercase and lowercase letters must match exactly

Comment: those are tested on same index and type. no.1 and no.3 are same version of query.. any difference between them?

Comment: What does this query yield? `{"query": { "wildcard": { "activityseq.raw": { "value": "MakeTicket>*" } } } }`

Comment: wow.. I got result as expected. I didn't get your mean of 'letters matching'. thanks.. you saved my time a lot :)

Comment: Awesome, glad we figured it out!!

Comment: @Val How to use same thing with attachment plugin? Can you check this once?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883942/how-to-allow-searching-with-spacial-character-in-elasticsearch-using-attachment