# How to allow searching with spacial character in Elasticsearch using Attachment plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on Spring Boot - JHipster base project.

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.8.6 with Attachment plugin.
In that, content field have data of my document.

Now, When i search '192.168.31.167' it gives an appropriate result. But, when i search this "192.168.31.167:9200" it gives an empty result.

In short, it's not working with spacial characters.
Can someone guide me. How to deal with this?

Mapping :

```
{
  "document" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "attachment" : {
            "properties" : {
              "content" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "content_length" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "content_type" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "content" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "createdDate" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "holder" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "tag" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Dummy Data :

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "document",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createdDate" : "2020-05-19T03:56:36+0000",
          "attachment" : {
            "content_type" : "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            "content" : "version: '2'\nservices:\n  docy-kibana:\n    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.6\n    ports:\n      - 5601:5601\n\n    environment:\n      SERVER_NAME: kibana.example.org\n      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://192.168.31.167:9200/\n      XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED: ${true}\n#      XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS.ENCRYPTIONKEY: test\n      XPACK_MONITORING_UI_CONTAINER_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED: ${true}",
            "content_length" : 390
          },
          "name" : "kibana_3_202005190926.yml",
          "holder" : 3,
          "id" : 1,
          "tag" : "configuration",
          "content" : "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"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch Request generated by code :

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [
            {
              "query_string" : {
                "query" : "*192.168.31.167:9200*",
                "fields" : [
                  "content^1.0",
                  "name^2.0",
                  "tag^3.0"
                ],
                "type" : "best_fields",
                "default_operator" : "or",
                "max_determinized_states" : 10000,
                "enable_position_increments" : true,
                "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
                "fuzzy_prefix_length" : 0,
                "fuzzy_max_expansions" : 50,
                "phrase_slop" : 0,
                "analyze_wildcard" : true,
                "escape" : false,
                "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
                "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard" : {
                "attachment.content" : {
                  "wildcard" : "*192.168.31.167:9200*",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [
            {
              "wildcard" : {
                "tag.keyword" : {
                  "wildcard" : "*information*",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "wildcard" : {
                "tag.keyword" : {
                  "wildcard" : "*user*",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Comment: You should provide a way for us to recreate the problem (mapping, query, sample document, etc). There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: Sorry for that, Question updated.

Comment: You can check this thread which provides a solution for extracting ip:port from a body of text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34986008/4604579 . The way I would proceed is to add another sub-field using that analyzer and search on that field.

Comment: Worth noting that if you were to choose the analyzer way as suggested in the above thread, I'd be happy to make sure the plugin works with ES 6.8.

Comment: @DhwanilPatel can you mark answer as accepted :) been really long time

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

You are using the `text` field to query the data which uses `standard` analyzer and split text on `:` as shown in below [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) call:

```
POST /_analyze
{
    "text" : "127.0.0.1:9200",
    "analyzer" : "standard"
}
```

**generated tokens**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "127.0.0.1",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "9200",
            "start_offset": 10,
            "end_offset": 14,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**Solution - 1**

Not optimized(wildcard query on the bigger index can cause severe perf issues) but as you are already using the wildcard it would work without changing analyzer and reindex the whole data(less overhead):

Use `.keyword` the field which is available on these text field which would not split the text into 2 tokens as shown below

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "127.0.0.1:9200",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 14,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

You can add `.keyword` as shown below:

```
             "content.keyword^1.0",
              "name.keyword^2.0",
              "tag.keyword^3.0"
```

**Solution- 2**

Refer the solution mentioned in the comment by @val which would involve creating a custom analyzer and reindex the whole data which will create expected tokens in the index and then search on them without using the expensive regex. **This will have a significantly better performance on large datasets but one time overhead of reindexing the whole data with new analyzer and queries.**

**Please choose whatever approach suits your business requirements better.**

Comment: The problem is that the keyword field is not analyzed and the ip:port is located in the middle of the string, so it would require a regexp query (or wildcarded query string) and that would deliver poor performance on a big amount of data. But it might work ok on a small amount of data

Comment: @Val totally agree, but he is already doing that, he is even using leading wildcard `*`.

Comment: @Val, agree, I know the efficient way and will update that in sometime, once again thanks for your valuable suggestions :)

Comment: Good, so he will be able to choose between two ways of doing it with the thread I provided above

Comment: @Val, ohh yeah didn't notice you already have a answer for that, then its easy for me, right away I am updating this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214154/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-val).

Comment: Actually i tried first approach earlier but it not working. QueryString & Wildcard  both return empty array. Currently i start with second way.

Comment: Yahh..., Actually i'm new in Elasticsearch and company have to give some urgent response so.... So i'm not able to invest that much time for analyse whole document - sorry for that both of you.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinjal, I do it with analyzer and tokenizer using ngram - working properly. But i'm not sure it's right or wrong. Can you suggest me?

Comment: @Val also need suggestion for above message form your side.

Comment: @DhwanilPatel yeah, you can do using n-gram tokenizer as well but be informed that it can create a lot of tokens and increase your index size which can cause perf issues if you are having huge no of docs in your elasticsearch.

Comment: Then, what is the other parallel solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214253/discussion-between-dhwanil-patel-and-opster-elasticsearch-ninja).

Comment: @DhwanilPatel one are multiple ways to implement a solution with diff trade-off, we don't know your functional and non-function requirement and without which its difficult to tell.